# Parsing issue in visual studio 2010 SP1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, parsing, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio starts re parsing the project when the project location is changed on disk.

Background:
I have created a large C++ project/solution (around 675MB source code) using visual studio 2010. It takes around 10 minutes to parse the files and create an .sdf file. The problem is that when I move this project (entire) folder to another location, it starts to re parse the project which is annoying and consumes 10 more minutes every time.

Is there a way in which visual studio uses the previously parsed info?

Comment: You can stop VS from putting those files in the project folder in the first place. I found answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706984/visual-studio-2010-c-project-remove-sdf-file) very relevant. What you are looking for is settings by name "Always Use Fallback Location". Create C:\Temp folder where all .sdf files will be stored, rather than individual project folders.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That thing works when I am moving the project within same machine/pc. But I have to share the project with others, what would be the procedure then?

Comment: share a folder on network, put the path in project settings.