# Visual Studio keeps putting IPCH folder in my solution folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I've followed this post on SO: [Visual Studio 2010 - C++ project - remove *.sdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706984/visual-studio-2010-c-project-remove-sdf-file) (so I've set my 'Fallback Location' to true and tried both leaving the fallback location blank and adding a different file path) in an attempt to stop the ipch folder from generating within my solution folder of my visual studio project. However, in visual studio 2015 update 3, this does not seem to solve the problem as the ipch folder keeps getting generated in my solution folder. Is there another setting I have to set in order to stop this from happening?

Comment: Hi Jason, the option ‘Always Use Fallback Location’ works fine in my VS community/enterprise 2015 with update 3, set it as ‘True’ can let the solution stop create the ‘ipch’ folder when you reload the previous C++ solutions that already manually delete the ‘ipch’ folder or create a new C++ solution. You can try to create a new C++ solution and check this issue again, if this issue persists, which means this issue is related to your VS. If not, this issue only relates to this solution. Create a new Blank Solution and add those projects to check if this solution is corrupted or not.

Comment: Hi Jason, does your issue is solved or not?

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't realize someone had answered this. I started another project in VS with the 'precompiled headers' box checked. Even with a new project the issue still seems to persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the new project also not works, this issue is more related to VS itself, you can have a try with the following to troubleshot:

1. Open the VS 2015 installation location, usually locates C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE and run the following commands, after each command, check this issue again.

devenv /resetuserdata: clear the old user data

devenv /safemode: run the VS with safe mode, if it works fine that means the installed extensions may be corrupted the VS, please go to Tool—Extensions and Updates… and remove all installed extensions one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: Fantastic. You are wonderful. It worked after step 3 and resetuserdata. Pretty annoying that had to be done though but what can you do.

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that your issue is solved, would you mind make it as answer? It will help other community member who meet the same or similar issue to easier search this.