# VS2010 with Visual Assist gone very slow, how to return to initial perfromance?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, visual-assist

I have a large C++ project being developed on VS2010 SP1 with VAssist which has started going very slow.  e.g. starting the debugger is taking about 4 minutes, whereas it was taking seconds yesterday.  I suspect it is down to either corrupt Intellisense support files after a crash, or other related temp files that need cleaning up.  I've deleted all breakpoints, as per this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249449/vs2010-debug-entry-very-slow) with no noticable difference.  I've also done a full clean rebuild of the project.  My next step is to delete all non-essential project files, and have VS and/or VAX rebuild them.  My questions are;

What are the following files in my project folder, and what is the downside of deleting them, documentation seems sparse?  .SDF, .OpenSDF, .SUO, .APS, VCXProj.Filters, VCXProj.User, .ipch (file in folder off the project folder)

Are there any other temporary files or related files, either VS or VAX, lurking in other folders that I should be clearing down on a regular basis?

Are there any of the above files I can simply backup and restore to avoid having to do this in future?

**Edit:**  Deleting the SDF, SUO and APS files speeds up the debug massively, but leaves the class wizard temporarily (I hope!) unavailable as the IDE is reporting that it is parsing header files.

**Edit2:**  And about 10 minutes later, ClassWizard is back, the SDF and SUO files are back though the SDR is slightly smaller, and the APS is not back.  Found a [useful related question regarding IPCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757402/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-ipch-folder-precompiled-headers).  Also cleared out a significant amount of junk out of the %TEMP% folder that appears VS related.

**Edit3:** As per answer in linked question above,  In Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols, emptying the symbol cached and only loading specified modules seems to remove bottlenecks coming in and out of debugging.

Comment: VS2010 is actually one of the slowest VS released. I tried it for couple of days after 2008 and switched to 2012 which is much much faster.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm planning on upgrading as soon as I have some breathing space after shipping my current release.  Are you using VS2012 with C++?

Comment: @evilruff if you read the Q you would see it has nothing to do with specific problem...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl That's why it's a comment but not an answer