# How to ban ''ipch'' from automatically generating in a c++ workplace(I am using vscode and I can't find the same settings in vs2010)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am doing my cpp homework and make a vscode workplace. But an ipch file is always generated automatically and it's so large and I don't think I will need it. So how to stop vscode from automatically generating ipch file.(There are some answers for VS2010 but not for vscode. I can't find the same setting in the VScode)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398287/ipch-files-on-a-visual-studio-project/41138541

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ipch files on a Visual Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398287/ipch-files-on-a-visual-studio-project)

Answer (score 0):

- Click [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-c-extension-march-2019-update/)

  > This is the official solution on VSCode's devblog. You can change the location via the “C_Cpp.intelliSenseCachePath” setting like this